# Angular 2 custom validation for numbers and decimal values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a custom validator that checks if an input field has a number entered into it. 
[image]

The code looks like so:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {

  static isNumberCheck(): ValidatorFn {
    return  (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {
      if (c.value !== undefined && (isNaN(c.value))) {
        return { 'value': true };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

But the issue I have is when I enter a decimal value it is raising the validation flag which I dont want. I want the input field to have whole numbers and decimal numbers. Can somebody please help me get this correct.

Below is my template code using parsleyjs for validation

```html
<div class="form-group row">
              <label for="upperbeltposition" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Upper Belt Position (mm) <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control input-transparent " id="upperbeltposition" type="text" formControlName="upperbeltposition"  data-parsley-trigger="blur"
                  required="required" data-parsley-type="number"/>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="platformxposition" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Platform X Position (mm) <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control input-transparent " id="platformxposition" type="text" formControlName="platformxposition"  data-parsley-trigger="blur"
                  required="required" data-parsley-type="number"/>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="platformyposition" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Platform Y Position (mm) <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control input-transparent " id="platformyposition" type="text" formControlName="platformyposition"  data-parsley-trigger="blur"
                  required="required" data-parsley-type="number"/>
              </div>
            </div>
```

and in my Component I am using Reactive form and below is my code

```js
upperbeltposition: ['', [Validators.required, NumberValidators.isNumberCheck]],
platformxposition: ['', [Validators.required, NumberValidators.isNumberCheck]],
platformyposition: ['', [Validators.required, NumberValidators.isNumberCheck]]
```

thanks!!

Comment: There is an extensive writeup on using NaN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN Something there may be helpful. And according to this reference, isNaN should be returning false for decimal values.

Comment: So, I need to remove that isNaN to allow whole numbers and decimal numbers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {

  static isNumberCheck(): ValidatorFn {
    return  (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {
      let number = /^[.\d]+$/.test(c.value) ? +c.value : NaN;
      if (number !== number) {
        return { 'value': true };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: No it is not working when I enter a decimal value like 1.1655

Comment: Check this jsfiddle, it works perfectly, https://jsfiddle.net/svLeh6m9/. Did you leave out the `+` sign before `c.value` ?

Comment: has it got to do with the parselyjs i have in my html file 'data-parsley-type="number"'

Comment: I don't know what it is for, but I am positive my answer should work as expected

Comment: I have copied your code as it is and not working with respect to my code setup

Comment: Console log `number` and `c.value` variables right before the `if` check and see what it outputs, not sure why it is parsing decimal as `NaN` since `NaN` is not equal to anything including itself

Comment: It prints this out
1.1111    NUMBERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR     1.1111
But I get that warning message which I show in the main question

Comment: its allowed multiple dots like 1......3

Answer (score 8):

can use ng-pattern validation

```
  ng-pattern="^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

can you please check once like this

```
  <label for="upperbeltposition" 
   class="col-md-6 col-form-label" 
   name="number">
     Upper Belt 
     Position (mm)
      <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
   <div class="col-md-5">
   <input 
    class="form-control input-transparent " 
    id="upperbeltposition" 
    type="text" 
    formControlName="upperbeltposition"  
     data-parsley-trigger="blur"
    required="required" 
    data-parsley-type="number"/> 
    <span  
     ng-show="submitForm && platformxposition 
      .number.$error.pattern">This value should be a valid number
   </span>

  </div>
```

You must add your form name. and input field name.$error.pattern

Answer (score 6):

Instead of creating a custom validator, you can also simply use the Validators.pattern

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern:

`['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[.\d]+$/)]]`

Comment: Seems to work well. I used this pattern for non-negative integers or decimals: Validators.pattern(/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/)

Answer (score -1):

A bit late, but perhaps helpfull for others.

This regexp will check for validity of decimal value:

```
^[-+]?([1-9]{1}\d*|0{1})(\.?)(?(2)\d+)$
```

The following values / patterns are valid:

- 123.7897
- 12
- 0.4897
- +238.345
- -238.345

Values starting with 00 are not valid , so although 00 is technically a number / decimal, functionally it is not.

Use this regexp in a pattern Validator or in your own Validator

```
Validators.pattern(/^[-+]?([1-9]{1}\d*|0{1})(\.?)(?(2)\d+)$/)
```