# how to adjust my regex to only allow max two numbers after dot appears

Tags: javascript, angular

I hope you can help me, I am capturing what is written in a component and I need that after the point comes out, it only allows me to type two more numbers

**event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, '.')**

```
1.11      ✓
11.11     ✓
1.112     x   => 1.11  => replace 2->''
```

I only need to validate the last option in that expression so that it does not allow me to type or it is replaced with '' if I try to type something else

Comment: Please read [ask]. Research on "validate decimal" gave answers: (a) [Regex for decimal with precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2), (b) [Angular: Custom validation for numbers & decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534938/angular-2-custom-validation-for-numbers-and-decimal-values#44602206).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this. Simply using [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) can limit the number of decimal places.

```js
function validate(s){
  return parseFloat(s).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(validate(1.11));
console.log(validate(11.11));
console.log(validate(1.112));
```